# toParse table.md to mysql

Tags: mysql, markdown

I was just wondering **how to** convert a `.md` table to a mysql table.
The `.md` files looks like this:

```
|myTitle|name|
|:--|--:|
```

I don't know if it is posible. The idea is to save a *local* copy and then to *sync* the entire work once done. This last part involving a remote server, can be omited. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What environment, language, etc are you working with? What code have you tried? Why is it not working for you?

Comment: I have a irrelevant number and type of tables -i always speak about `table.md`. The "plan" is to prepare those tables to be integrated on `mySQL` databe in the future. So i'm just starting to planing the work, the choices, options, etc.

Comment: ... So your question would be, Why don't write the `data` directly with `mySQL` syntax. The answer is, because that "irrelevant" tables is something like esporiuos and marginal, resulting on a very easy/quickly way, to do the work over `.md` files and try to convert after.